# Warning "ISO C++ forbids variable-size array" with constant size array

Tags: c++, g++

I have a c++ program in which constants are stored within a class. And somewhere else in the code I use one of these constants as an array size.

Here is a sample:

**Constants.h**

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

class Constants
{
public:
    static const unsigned int C_BufferSize;
};

#endif
```

**Constants.cpp**

```
#include "Constants.h"

const unsigned int Constants::C_BufferSize(128);
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Constants.h"

int main()
{
    char buffer[Constants::C_BufferSize];
    return 0;
}
```

---

When I compile this code with `-std=c++11 -pedantic` I got the following warning:

> main.cpp:5:37: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘buffer’ [-Wvla]

I don't really understand the error since the size is a constant, my guess is that at compile time the size is unknown.

The error can be bypassed using a heap allocated table (allocated with new), but I'm forbidden to use dynamic memory allocation. Therefore I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: `#define C_BUFSIZE 128` or whatnot.

Comment: @BЈовић Biggest assertion ever.

Comment: You could use an enum, or C++11 initializer (`{128}`), and I think you could even intialize in-class (`= 128`).

Comment: Unless you wanted to use said constant in an `#if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *definition* is required and searched for, at link-time. So yes, the size is unknown during the compilation phase.

You're write this:

```
class Constants
{
public:
    static const unsigned int C_BufferSize = 128; //initialize here
};
```

And then only provide the *definition* in `.cpp` file:

```
const unsigned int Constants::C_BufferSize; //no initialization here
```

---

But then it makes better sense to make `Constants` a namespace instead of a class:

```
namespace Constants  //NOTE : a namespace now
{
    static const unsigned int BufferSize = 128; 
};
```

Seems more natural to me.

Comment: After a few tests it seems that the definition in cpp file is not mandatory.

Comment: @Mika it is if you *odr-use* it by e.g. taking its address. If you take its address but don't define it in a .cpp file you should get a linker error (this is for a `static` data member, not a global).

Answer (score 0):

Warning reason - as mentioned by @nawaz already (*variable size in array at compile time - might not be supported/allowed by all compilers*).

can be attempted this way instead:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(Constants::C_BufferSize);
```

Typically the above issue would arise when doing some `char*` conversion to `string` (limited by actual data size in the char-buffer). Therefore in that case, this can be used something like;

```
std::string ConvertCharDataBySizeToString(const char* s, std::size_t size)
{
    std::vector<char> data(s, s+size);
    return ( std::string(data.begin(), data.end()) );
}
```

Reference/s [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2392317/4361073).